# Android elevated view animation not smooth

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to rotate a simple imageview which has an elevation of 5dp.

> ```
>         animRotate=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgProgress, "rotationY", 0, 360);
>         animRotate.setDuration(ANIM_DURATION);
>         animRotate.setRepeatCount(5);
>         animRotate.start();
> ```

The animation for the above code is smooth if the android:elevation value for the ImageView is not set in the layout file. But when i set the elevation, the animation becomes jerky.

Can someone please suggest a fix?

Comment: whether you set it in xml or by calling some set* method should'n have any difference, after all, setting it in xml causes the same method to be called when creating your view

Comment: @pskink my issue is when i set the elevation the animation is jerky. If i remove the elevation it becomes smooth again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is that you create and run animatuion at once. As docs say, it is better first to init your animation

```
//OnCreate
animRotate=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgProgress, "rotationY", 0, 360);
animRotate.setDuration(ANIM_DURATION);
animRotate.setRepeatCount(5);
```

And then when it is time for animation to be fired run it

```
animRotate.start();
```

Also, consider reading about what PivotX and PivotY are, it may be useful.

Also, using default interpolator will give strange result for rotating 5 times - i think using simple linear interpolator is much better choice.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! I tried initializing the animation in the onCreate() method. But there wasn't too much of a difference. However, i think i see a slight improvement tough. But still, it isn't as smooth as the animation with 0 elevation. I also tried the LinearInterpolator but it didn't change anything.

Comment: LinearInterpolator would change your animation - by default you have another one, which has not linear changes. 2 When do you call start() method? post your code please